# Deep link to particular email in content builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

Is it possible to get/generate a link to a specific email in content builder, so that it can be sent to a co-worker/saved in a project management tool etc.

Content builder seems to be at:

https://mc.xx.exacttarget.com/cloud/#app/Content%20Builder/

This is the url for the list of emails, and for the builder itself.  Can a mailing ID go on in the query string or something to get to a particular email?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you have tracking extracts coming out of SFMC, there is a column in the "SendJobs" table that has an email preview URL.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_sendjobs.htm&type=5